# How to sum lengths of array properties inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object that looks like this:

```js
let arr = {
  names: ['John', 'Paul'],
  phones: ['iPhone', 'Samsung', 'Huawei'],
  clothesBrands: ['HM', 'Zara']
}
```

I need to sum the lengths of the arrays. I can do it like this:

```
arr.names.length + arr.phones.length + arr.clothesBrands.length
```

and the result is 7.

How can I do it in a clean way if I don't know all the keys?

Comment: Will the key values always be an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the length of the `.flat`tened array of values:

```js
const arr = {
  names: ['John', 'Paul'],
  phones: ['iPhone', 'Samsung', 'Huawei'],
  clothesBrands: ['HM', 'Zara']
};

console.log(Object.values(arr).flat().length);
```

Comment: Yes `flat` is the best way

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**object.values**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

**`Object.values`** will give you all the values in Object and with **`reduce`** we calculate total length.

```js
let obj = {names: ['John', 'Paul'], phones: ['iPhone', 'Samsung', 'Huawei'], clothesBrands: ['HM', 'Zara']}

let op = Object.values(obj).reduce( (out, inp) => out + inp.length, 0)

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reduce
. Get all the values in the objects and in reduce add the lengths of the arrays one by one

```js
var arr = {
  names: ['John', 'Paul'],
  phones: ['iPhone', 'Samsung', 'Huawei'],
  clothesBrands: ['HM', 'Zara']
}
console.log(Object.values(arr).reduce((acc, e) => acc += e.length, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

For in loops are your friend when working with objects.
Example to solve your problem below:

```js
var arr = {names: ['John', 'Paul'], phones: ['iPhone', 'Samsung', 'Huawei'], clothesBrands: ['HM', 'Zara'], hello: 1};

var totalLength = 0;

for(var char in arr){
  // Confirm that the key value is an array before adding the value.
  if(Array.isArray(arr[char])){
    totalLength += arr[char].length; 
  }
}
console.log(totalLength);
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)on `Object.values` and check whether the value is array by `Array.isArray()`

```js
let obj ={names: ['John', 'Paul'], phones: ['iPhone', 'Samsung', 'Huawei'], clothesBrands: ['HM', 'Zara']}
let sum = Object.values(obj).reduce((ac,a) => {
  return Array.isArray(a) ? ac + a.length : ac
},0)
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another alternative using [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate over the object `keys` directly:

```js
let arr = {
  names: ['John', 'Paul'],
  phones: ['iPhone', 'Samsung', 'Huawei'],
  clothesBrands: ['HM', 'Zara']
}

let totalLen = 0;

for (k in arr)
{
    Array.isArray(arr[k]) && (totalLen += arr[k].length);
}

console.log(totalLen);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this.

```js
const arr = {names: ['John', 'Paul'], phones: ['iPhone', 'Samsung', 'Huawei'], clothesBrands: ['HM', 'Zara']};

const sum = Object.values(arr).reduce((acc, {length}) => {
 return acc = length ? acc+ length : acc; 
}, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: May I please know the reason of downvoting?

Comment: I am not the one who did, but one possible reason is use of filter when you can do the same in reduce itself. if it's array add length else add 0

Comment: @CodeManiac I tried to use destructing of the `Array.length` property so if I don't filter it beforehand I would get an error if the object in question is not an array.

Comment: It will work even without filter. try removing filter and run your code. well if anything don't have length property it will result in `undefined` and you can use ternary operator to check if length is `undefined` or not and than add value accordingly in reduce.