# Javascript: How to count the length of multiple arrays dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to count length of all arrays in variant object dynamically? Is there any best to do achieve this dynamically?

```
const variants = {
  cars: ["ford", "honda", "bmw"],
  bikes: ["ducati", "yamaha"],
  colors: ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
}
```

Current implementation as in below:

```
const totalCars = variants.cars.length;
const totalBikes = variants.bikes.length;
const totalcolors = variants.colors.length;

console.log(totalCars + totalBikes + totalcolors)
// result: 8
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum lengths of array properties inside an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820496/how-to-sum-lengths-of-array-properties-inside-an-object)

Answer (score 4):

```
Object.values(variants).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val.length, 0)
```

Comment: Im getting following error in IDE. `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

Comment: do you use Typescript? TS should automatically detects types based on your code. The error means it cannot understand and you should define your types manually

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that same  data structure will be used:

```
const lengthOfVariants = Object.keys(variants).map( variation => variants[variation].length ) // [ 3 , 2 , 3 ]
const totalLength = lenghtOfVariants.reduce((a,b) => a+b , 0 ); // 8
```

To answer in detail,

1. the 1st line will iterate through each key-value pair and get it's length.
2. the 2nd line will add the result obtained in the previous line and store it in a variable

Edit: adjusting for `null`

```
const lengthOfVariants = Object.keys(variants).map( variation => variants[variation] ? variants[variation].length : 0  ) 
const totalLength = lenghtOfVariants.reduce((a,b) => a+b , 0 );
```

Comment: What if any of these array returned null or undefined ? How we can check on that?
`Eg: variants { colors: undefined, ... }`

Comment: change `variation => variants[variation].length` to `variation => variants[variation].length || 0`

Comment: This would make sure that if it's unable to do anything about a certain key-value pair, it will give up and return `0`

Comment: I'm getting `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')`

Comment: edited the answer to adjust for both `null` and `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that

```js
const variants = {
  cars: ["ford", "honda", "bmw"],
  bikes: ["ducati", "yamaha"],
  colors: ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
}

let totalLength = 0;
for ( const v in variants){
  totalLength += variants[v].length;
}

console.log(totalLength);
```

Answer (score 1):

This sums the lengths of the top level arrays within `variants`.  Anything that's not an array gets ignored.

```js
const variants = {
  cars: ["ford", "honda", "bmw"],
  bikes: ["ducati", "yamaha"],
  colors: ["red", "blue", "yellow"],
  junk: 9
}

let output = Object.values(variants).reduce((a, v) => a + (Array.isArray(v) ? v.length : 0), 0);
console.log(output);
```